# Python, Passing a list to a method in order to iterate yields argument of type instance not iterable?

Tags: python

**Method to check if a pkg name is already inside another list thats populated with structures:**

**For example**: test_pkg_list[] would contain something along the following:

```
test_pkg_list[0]: 

name = git
version = 1.0
description = git package

test_pkg_list[1]:

name = opengl
version = 1.25
description = graphics

So on...
```

So my goal was to check the list for any duplicates of names.

```
def _pkg_exists_in_list(self, list, pkg_name):
        if len(list) >= 1:
            if any(pkg_name in item for item in list):
                return True 
            else:
                return False
        else:
            return False
```

**I pass in two parameters:**

```
test_pkg_list = [] #Note that this list does populate over time, at first its empty.
pkg_name = 'git'

#Call the method an pass the paramters
if self._pkg_exists_in_list(test_pkg_list, pkg_name) is False:
  #No duplicates found continue
else:
  #We found duplicate, stop.
```

**I continue to receive the following exception error:**

```
argument of type 'instance' is not iterable
```

Comment: Could you show the traceback?

Comment: You really shouldn't have an argument with name `list`; that can cause problems by overwriting the `list` built-in.

Comment: This depends entirely on what `test_pkg_list` is populated with (which you never provide a hint to), since it is `pkg_name in item` that raises the exception, *not* `for item in list`. (We know this because if it were an non-iterable instance, then `len(list)` in the previous line would raise the error).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is way more complex than it needs to be.

```py
def _pkg_exists_in_list(self, the_list, pkg_name):
    return pkg_name in the_list
```

Here's why:

```py
def _pkg_exists_in_list(self, list, pkg_name):  # don't call it list; don't overwrite built-ins
        if len(list) >= 1:   # Unnecessary; [] resolves Boolean to False
            if any(pkg_name in item for item in list): # can just check if an item is in a list using the `in` statement; no need to match every string to every string
                return True # Can just return the evaluation of an expression; poor form to explicitly return True/False after if statement
            else:
                return False
    else:
        return False
```

#### Update:

I guess I should point out as said in the comments that `item in mylist` is not identical to your code `any(mystring in item for item in mylist)`, but rather is equivalent, more verbosely, to `any(mystring == item for item in mylist)`.  However, I'm guessing that you actually meant `==` than substring matching with `in`.

#### Second update:

While I like **Alex**'s idea of using a dictionary, it might not be necessary.

```py
import re
def _pkg_exists_in_list(self, the_list, pkg_name):
    return any(re.search(r'name = ' + pkg_name, item) for item in the_list)
```

I guess it's just a question of which is more efficient.

#### Update 2.1:

I win.

```py
C:\Users\JJ>python -m timeit -s "p = ['''name = git\nversion = 1.0\nd
escription = git package''', '''name = opengl\nversion = 1.25\ndescription = gra
phics''']; import re" "dictlist = []" "for item in p:" " d = {}" " for line in i
tem.splitlines():" "  k, v = line.split('=')" "  d[k.strip()] = v.strip()" " dic
tlist.append(d)" "any('git' == x['name'] for x in dictlist)"
100000 loops, best of 3: 5.38 usec per loop

C:\Users\JJ>python -m timeit -s "p = ['''name = git\nversion = 1.0\nd
escription = git package''', '''name = opengl\nversion = 1.25\ndescription = gra
phics''']; import re" "any(re.search(r'name = ' + 'git', item) for item in p)"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.36 usec per loop
```

Comment: No, that's not the same. `obj in a_list` = `any(item == obj for item in a_list)`, but OP's code checks whether `any(item in obj for item in a_list)`.

Comment: @delnan, that is true, but I'm relatively confident that he actually meant `item == obj`.  There was just a previous answer that pointed that out that was recently deleted, I guess.

Comment: There's a new-deleted answer, but it just makes the same assumption without any rationale. What makes you so confident?

Comment: It was just a guess.  The code in the OP was written pretty unpythonically, so I was guessing that OP isn't that familiar with Python, and mixing up `in` and `==` with substrings is not unheard of for Python beginners.  Since that point you made was noted in a different answer, I didn't feel a need to restate it.  In any case, I pointed out the difference in my answer.

Comment: I updated my question, the list i'm trying to pass in is not populated by simple strings, each index holds a structure that has a couple of properties that can be set. Basically the list holds 1578 structures that each have around 5 propeties to provide debian package information.

Comment: Haha! It's not all about speed ;)

Comment: @Alex you tell yourself that as my code leaves yours trailing 4 microseconds behind in the dust.

Answer (score 3):

I would convert your list of strings to a list of `dict`s, then search using something like this:

```
test_pkg_list = [
"""name = git
version = 1.0
description = git package""",

"""name = opengl
version = 1.25
description = graphics"""]

dictlist = []

# Turn into a list of dictionaries
for item in test_pkg_list:
    d = {}
    for line in item.splitlines():
        k, v = line.split('=')
        d[k.strip()] = v.strip()
    dictlist.append(d)

print dictlist
# [
#    {'version': '1.0', 'name': 'git', 'description': 'git package'}, 
#    {'version': '1.25', 'name': 'opengl', 'description': 'graphics'}
# ]

searchname = 'git'

# Now search by name
print any(searchname == x['name'] for x in dictlist)
```

---

If you don't want the hassle of converting to dict, you could do something as simple as:

```
>>> searchname = 'git'
>>> print any(searchname in line for line in test_pkg_list)
True
>>> searchname = 'empty'
>>> print any(searchname in line for line in test_pkg_list)
False
>>> searchname = 'version' # This is a problem
>>> print any(searchname in line for line in test_pkg_list)
True

# Or to ensure it only matches the name:
>>> print any('name = ' + searchname in line for line in test_pkg_list)
False
>>> searchname = 'git'
>>> print any('name = ' + searchname in line for line in test_pkg_list)
True
>>> searchname = 'version'
>>> print any('name = ' + searchname in line for line in test_pkg_list)
False
```

---

Or you could extract just the names:

```
for line in test_pkg_list:
    firstline = line.splitlines()[0]
    name = firstline.split('=')[1].strip()
    print name
```

One line:

```
>>> names = [line.splitlines()[0].split('=')[1].strip() for line in test_pkg_list]
['git', 'opengl']
```

Then compare:

```
>>> 'git' in names
True
>>> 'test' in names
False
```

Performance is comparable to using `re`: (65% of the speed)

```
>>> timeit.timeit("any(re.search(r'name = ' + 'git', item) for item in p)", "p = ['''name = git\nversion = 1.0\ndescription = git package''', '''name = opengl\nversion = 1.25\ndescription = graphics''']; import re")
2.338025673656987

>>> timeit.timeit("'git' in [line.splitlines()[0].split('=')[1].strip() for line in p]", "p = ['''name = git\nversion = 1.0\ndescription = git package''', '''name = opengl\nversion = 1.25\ndescription = graphics''']")
3.5689878827767245
```